# Julia PyCall.pyfunction with wrapped julia objects from Python

Tags: python, julia, pycall

For performance reasons I would like to wrap Julia functions I am using in Python with the `PyCall.pyfunctionret` and `PyCall.pyfunction` wrappers.

One of my Julia functions returns an object that is explicitly not converted to a python object using the `PyCall.pyfunctionret` function. Now I would like to pass this object back into Julia and wrap the function with the `PyCall.pyfunction` wrapper.

The following example works, but from my understanding it does not actually benefit much from using the `pyfunction` wrapper, since I have to use the `PyAny` type and PyCall would still have to infer the type of the object. I would like to specify something more specific than PyAny in my call to `pyfunction`.

So I have this in julia:

```
function example(firstnumber, secondnumber)
    return Float64[firstnumber, secondnumber]
end

function useobject(obj::Vector{Float64})
    println("this is the object:", obj)
end
```

And in python:

```py
from julia import Main
Main.eval('using PyCall; include("juliafunctions.jl")')

jl_function = Main.eval("pyfunctionret(example, Any, Float64, Float64)")

# These two work as expected - the first returns a converted python object
# (which is a numpy array in this case) and the second returns a simple
# wrapped julia object.
python_object = Main.example(1, 2)
jl_object = jl_function(1, 2)

# Now here is my problem. This works, but I would like to replace
# PyAny here, to avoid the automatic type inference pyjulia has to do in
# this case:
jl_secondfunction = Main.eval("pyfunction(useobject, PyAny)")
jl_secondfunction(jl_object)
```

My questions are the following:

- Is my understanding of `pyfunction` and the use of the `PyAny` type correct, as in that PyCall still needs to infer the type of the passed in object before attempting any conversion?
- What should I put instead of `PyAny`, to correctly indicate to PyCall, that I am only going to pass in a wrapped julia object which needs to be unwrapped, not converted?

I also tried `Main.eval("pyfunction(useobject, PyObject)")` but that just doesn't work at all and I tried `Main.eval("pyfunction(useobject, Any)")`, which comes slightly closer to what I want because it passes the wrapped python object into Julia. However, that fails since it doesn't find the correct method for type `PyObject`.

Comment: Asking this kind of question in the related repository would be more likely to be answered.

Comment: I posted an issue on the repository here: [https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl/issues/1013](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl/issues/1013). Thank you for your input @Shayan